# email using google sheets, checking for different possible strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to generate an email when a column is edited.  I am using this as a tool to notify specific staff members that students are coming to their offices after signing out of a classroom.

I have tested it and it works.  My question is this, I would like to adjust the script so that I can run it so that when specific students sign out that it triggers an email.  However, my list of students will be lengthy and needs to change on a regular basis.  I will be keeping track of the students in a separate sheet, below in my if statement where col6==“Guidance Counselor” can that be replaced somewhere with a list that is referenced from a separate sheet so that on the separate sheet in column1 I have Student1, Student2, Student3, ... listed and whenever one of the names on that list becomes the cellValue it sends an email to me.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // EVENT VARIABLES
  let range = e.range;
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let col = e.range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();

  let studentName = sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  let cellLocation = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  let url = ( url )

  if ( col == 6 && cellValue == "Guidance Counselor") {
    // Browser.msgBox('It works');
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      'my email',
      studentName + ' to Guidance!',
      url + '&range=' + cellLocation
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  let lsh = e.source.getSheetByName('StudentList')
  let list = lsh.getRange(2,1,lsh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  let studentName = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue();
  let user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if ( e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.value == "Guidance Counselor" && ~list.indexOf(studentName) && sh.getName() == "your sheet name") {
    MailApp.sendEmail('my email',studentName + ' to Guidance!',url + '&range=' + e.range.getA1Notation());
  }
}
```